# How to add Java classes to a Worklight adapter when using CLI

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-cli

I am trying to add Java classes to my adapter as described in the tutorial [Using Java in Adapters](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_12_Using_Java_in_adapters.pdf). However, I am trying to do that from the CLI.

When I do:

- wl create WLProject
- cd WLProject
- wl add adapter
- copy the Java class (Calculator1.java) to server/java/com/worklight/customcode
- wl start

The build process fails and no war file is created;

When I do:

- wl create WLProject
- cd WLProject
- wl add adapter
- wl start
- copy the Java class (Calculator1.java) to server/java/com/worklight/customcode
- wl build
- wl deploy
- wl invoke

The invocation fails. When I inspect the war file, the Calculator1.class has not been deployed.

So the question is: how can I add Java classes to an adapter when using the CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug to me. It looks like the build process fails when introducing server-side artifacts.
This might be not currently supported in the CLI, but I can't imagine such a limitation...

I've opened a defect to have this looked at.
[You can open a PMR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639) (support ticket) to receive a fix if/when available.

---

If I do the following,
the .war file is being generated.

```
wl create myTestProject
cd myTestProject/
wl build
```

But if I do this,
the .war file is not generated which is why everything else then fails:

```
wl create myTestProject
mkdir -p myTestProject/server/java/com/worklight/customcode
cp Calculator.java myTestProject/server/java/com/worklight/customcode
cd myTestProject/
wl build
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a fix for this currently available in the latest version of the CLI?

Comment: @Opossum, Yes, as part of APAR PI23231 a fix for this was introduced to both 6.2 and 6.3; download the latest CLI for either of these versions and it should be fine. If you are encountering it still, you can open a new question about what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

There's an invalid classpathref in the build file that's producing the WAR.

You can edit `[CLI Install Location]/worklight-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml` to fix this issue with the classpathref.

**If you're not planning on using any server runtime libraries:**
On line 132, you can remove the attribute classpathref="server-classpath".

**If you plan on using server runtime libraries:**
You'll need to add the "server-classpath" to be used when compiling your code. Before the `build-WAR` target in the build.xml file, you can add the following
`<path id="server-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${worklight.jars.dir}" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar" />
    <fileset dir="[your home directory]/.worklight/6.2.0/server/wlp/dev" includes="**/*.jar" />
 </path>`

Please note that the second fileset, you'll have to change `[your home directory]` to the appropriate path. Adding both of these filesets includes the worklight runtime and the server runtime when compiling your classes.

**When you've made your changes:**
Restart the server. At this point, the Calculator1 class should be added to your WAR.

Comment: nsand, is this expected to be fixed?

Comment: @IdanAdar Yup, it sounds like a bad problem to encounter.